# Array with semicolon

Tags: php, arrays

oke simple question

```
$wew=array(111,222,333);
print_r($wew);
```

the output will be like this

```
Array ( [0] => 111,222,333 )
```

but what i want is like this

```
Array ( [0] => 111, [1] => 222, [2] => 333 )
```

how to do that ?

Comment: Back up a little, and please post `print_r($_POST)`. The structure you are showing doesn't make much sense from the posted form, unless there's more to this we cannot see (like a framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r(array(111,222,333));` (your code minus the array) would print:

`Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 222 [2] => 333 )`

So you must have an additional array. In order to match the first example it'd have to be:

`print_r(array("111,222,333"));`

Comment: hi, thanks your answer
but why if i have this
`<input type='text' name='fi[nim]' value='111,222,333' />`
`print_r(array(111,222,333));`
the output will be like
`Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 222 [2] => 333 )`
but when i use this
`print_r(array($fi['nim']));`
the output wil be like
`Array ( [0] => 111,222,333 )`

Comment: here we go, now we are talking ;)

Comment: You're input is giving you text, "111,222,333" is a single string, not an array. `array(111,222,333)` is an actual array with three elements

Comment: You may be looking for the `explode` function. `explode($fi['nim'])`

Comment: Hey it works, thanks
i have been implement like explode(',',$fi['nim']);

Comment: hi i want to ask again.

i have this
`$ex= explode(',',$fi['nim']);

$post_field = array('nims'=>array($ex));`
`print_r($post_field);`
the output will be like this

`Array
(
    [nims] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 111
                    [1] => 222
                    [2] => 333
                )

        )

)`

but what i want is like this

`Array
(
    [nims] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 222
            [2] => 333
        )

)`
How to do that ?
Thanks before.

Comment: Seems like you'd want `array('nims' => explode(',',$fi['nim']));`

Comment: oke, so explode is array to ?

Comment: `explode` splits a string at every instance of a character/substring. In this case the comma. By splitting the string, it creates an `array` of the results.

Answer (score 0):

for that kind of output, it should be:

```
$wew=array('111,','222,','333,');
print_r($wew);
```

would give:

```
Array ( [0] => 111, [1] => 222, [2] => 333, )
```

Comment: `$wew=array(111,222,333)` would give the same

Comment: @i-- note that there's comma (',') after every values in output